# Blank screen on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have an Xamarin-project that I've been working on for quite some time.
But suddenly the main interface is blank when I open it. On the iOS simulator and on my iOS device.

No error when the app build. I get my splashscreen, and then just a white blank screen.

I am using Xamarin in Visual Studio 15 with MVVMCross and storyboards.

I have tried the following:

1. Reset iOS simulator
2. Cleaned solution in Visual Studio
3. Tried another storyboard as main interface

Any ideas?

Edit: Here is my AppDelegate.cs file:

```
using Foundation;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using MvvmCross.iOS.Platform;
using MvvmCross.Platform;
using UIKit;
using Tjenester.Touch.Util;

namespace Tjenester.Touch
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate
    {
        UIWindow _window;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            _window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            var setup = new Setup(this, _window);
            setup.Initialize();

            var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
            startup.Start();

            _window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

            MessageService.Initialize(this);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my CustomAppStart.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Tjenester.Core.Helpers;
using Tjenester.Core.Services.Authentication;
using Tjenester.Core.ViewModels;
using Tjenester.Core.ViewModels.ViewModelParameters;
using Xamarin.Auth;
using Tjenester.Core;
using System.Threading;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;

/// <summary>
/// Custom Application start procedure to be fed to MvvmCross.
/// If we already have Username and Password, try login and proceed to the page.
/// TODO refactor when azure and google are added
/// </summary>
public class CustomAppStart : MvxNavigatingObject, IMvxAppStart
{

    public void Start(object hint = null)
    {
        ShowViewModel<LoginViewModel>(new LoginPageParameters() {TryLogin = true});
    }
}
```

Here is my Setup.cs:

```
using UIKit;
using Tjenester.Core.Helpers;
using Foundation;
using Tjenester.Core.Services.Media;
using Tjenester.Touch.Services;
using Tjenester.Core.Services.Storage;
using Tjenester.Core.Services.Scripting;
using Tjenester.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Tjenester.Core.Services.Http;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using MvvmCross.iOS.Platform;
using MvvmCross.Localization;
using MvvmCross.Platform;
using MvvmCross.Platform.Platform;
using MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins;
using Tjenester.Touch.Services.Http;
using Tjenester.Touch.Services.Storage;

namespace Tjenester.Touch
{
    public class Setup : MvxIosSetup
    {
        private readonly UIWindow _win;
        private readonly MvxApplicationDelegate _del;

        public Setup(MvxApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, UIWindow window)
            : base(applicationDelegate, window)
        {
            _del = applicationDelegate;
            _win = window;
        }

        protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
        {
            UIContext.SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            if (NSLocale.PreferredLanguages.Length > 0) {
                var pref = NSLocale.PreferredLanguages [0];
                Settings.Language = pref.Substring (0, 2);
            }
            //Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IFileUploadService, TouchFileUploadService>();
            Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IHttpClientFactory, HttpClientFactory>();
            Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IStorageService, StorageService>();
            Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IPicturePickerService, TouchPicturePickerService>();
            return new Core.App();
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<System.Reflection.Assembly> ValueConverterAssemblies
        {
            get
            {
                var toReturn = base.ValueConverterAssemblies.ToList();
                toReturn.Add(typeof(MvxLanguageConverter).Assembly);
                return toReturn;
            }
        }

        protected override IMvxPluginConfiguration GetPluginConfiguration(Type plugin)
        {
            if (plugin == typeof(Tjenester.Core.Services.Scripting.PluginLoader))
            {
                return new MvxScriptServiceConfiguration()
                    .UseDefaultScriptBindings()
                ;
            }
            return base.GetPluginConfiguration(plugin);
        }

        protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace()
        {
            return new MvxDebugTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your AppDelegate methods look like? Could you post some of the most important methods?

Comment: My AppDelegate.cs added on top.

Comment: What does you AppStart look like? What does your Setup look like?

Comment: These are also added on top

Answer (score 0):

Could you try initializing your MvxIosViewPresenter manually to get some more information?

So, you would have to use the following lines (ApplicationDelegate.cs):

```
_window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
var presenter = new MvxIosViewPresenter(this, _window);

var setup = new Setup(this, presenter);
setup.Initialize();

var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
startup.Start();

var rootViewController = new FirstView(); // You need to have created this ViewController
_window.RootViewController = rootViewController;

_window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

return true;
```

If this works for you, then it means that your storyboard hasn't been created correctly. Your FirstViewController designed on your storyboard doesn't know about your "Code" version of your class FirstViewViewController that implements MvxViewController.

Wanna give that a bash and see how it goes? This is not an elegant solution, but could give some insight.

Comment: I found out what causes this error. If I uncheck "Auto layout" on the storyboard it loads, but of course now out of proportions. Could there be something wrong with how the storyboard is made that causes this?

Comment: That sounds really strange. Blank starting screens on my part have usually been to not setting the class names correctly on the storyboards views.